# Twitter API and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I'm just messing right now with react and thought I would try to make an app that could search for tweets. I basically just follwed the [npm twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) examples but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Twitter from 'twitter';
import config from './config.js'



class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.Client = new Twitter(config);
    this.searchTwitter = this.searchTwitter.bind(this);
  }

  searchTwitter(){
    this.Client.get('search/tweets', {q: 'node.js'}, function(error, tweets, response) {
   console.log(tweets);
 });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">The Test App</h1>
        </header>
        <button style = {{height: "50px", width: "150px"}} onClick = {this.searchTwitter}> CLICK ME </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's just a quick test where you click the button and it searches for tweets and logs them to the console. The problem is I just get 'undefined' every time and I have checked the keys and tokens so I don't think that's the issue. 
I've never tried to use this API so any help is very appreciated

Comment: Maybe there are errors, could you proceed this way `if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);} else {console.log(error)}`. In this case, if there are errors they will be log to the console

Comment: Are you sure your twitter configuration is correct and can connect with twitter as proper

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the twitter api doesn't support CORS request, So we cannot make any calls to the api through the browser, hence its not working for you.
Please refer to the below link for more details: 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/will-twitter-api-support-cors-headers-soon/28276/4